# How would I call a wildcard variable in python POST method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wildcard, web.py

I am still fresh with python and am trying to get my web app to return a wildcard variable (as a catch-all). Here is my current code, which functions correctly for defined dictionary paths as well as empty form responses, but I cant get it to function for undefined entries:

```
def POST(self):
    form = web.input(action=None)

    if session.room:
        if form.action:
            session.room = session.room.go(form.action)
        if not form.action:
            web.seeother("/")
        return render.show_room(room=session.room)

    else:
        web.seeother("/")
```

Here is my dictionary for reference as to what I'm attempting ('*' is the wildcard catch-all):

```
escape_pod.add_paths({
    '2': the_end_winner,
    '*': the_end_loser
})

the_bridge.add_paths({
    'throw the bomb': bridge_death,
    'slowly place the bomb': escape_pod,
    '*': the_bridge
})

laser_weapon_armory.add_paths({
    '132': the_bridge,
    '*': laser_death
})

central_corridor.add_paths({
    'shoot!': shoot_death,
    'dodge!': dodge_death,
    'barrel roll': poor_sport,
    'tell a joke': laser_weapon_armory,
    '*': central_corridor
})

poor_sport.add_paths({
    'let me try again': central_corridor,
    '*': poor_sport
})
```

I have gotten this to work once but for some reason my editor didnt save that version in the local file history? Any help is welcomed.. Thank you!

Here is the stack trace from my terminal. I know the issue, I just cant seem to figure out how to reword my function to call the wildcard.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/application.py", line 462, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/application.py", line 438, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/Users/isabey/projects/gothonweb/bin/app.py", line 48, in POST
    return render.show_room(room=session.room)
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/template.py", line 1020, in template
    return self._base(t(*a, **kw))
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/template.py", line 881, in __call__
    return BaseTemplate.__call__(self, *a, **kw)
  File "/Users/isabey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/web/template.py", line 808, in __call__
    return self.t(*a, **kw)
  File "templates/show_room.html", line 19, in __template__
    $room.description
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: For further info on this one, basically I am trying to get the page to loop back to itself upon submission of a non defined response.

Comment: Also if this helps at all, this is the stack trace from terminal. I'm running this through port 8080 on my localhost with the web.py framework.
*edit* stack trace is too long to post..